# kill python listener which opened matplotlib figure

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i wrote a visualization with matplotlib in python.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def callback(data):
do something
plt.show()

def listener():
rospy.Subscriber('topic', data, callback)
rospy.spin()

 Main function.
if __name__ == '__main__':
# Initialize the node and name it.

   rospy.init_node('pylistener', anonymous = True)
   # Go to the main loop.
   listener()
```

i want to print my figure. The problem is when he get a message he stop till i close the figure. That is fine. But when i want to close the program with ctrl+c the program crash and i have to close the terminal.

It is possible to kill the node and the python program after i close the figure?

Or what i can do against this crashing? It is really annoying that i have to close the terminal and restart it.

thank you for your help and sry i am new on python

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60883/kill-python-listener-which-opened-matplotlib-figure/) by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 222 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-04-19**:
Also, where do you define data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that you're sending more than just one data packet, thus attempting plot more than once. That's the reason why it hangs.

`ps -ef` in another terminal will show you the PID for the program and a `kill PID` should stop the process.

In any case, to get past the core issue, I'd suggest using [savefig](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) saving files with a unique name, appending timestamp is one approach, and the you can print at your leisure. You should use [clf](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.clf) after you save the figure though.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-04-17**:
yes i send more then one message. It is not possible to kill the node and the python program after i received the first one and I closed the figure?

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-04-17**:
if you kill the node then the data that you're also killing the subscriber to the data that trying to plot.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-04-17**:
My suggestion is to use savefig/clf instead of using show(), since that method "block[s] until the figures have been closed"

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-04-18**:
I only want to see one plot. So it doesn't matter if my plot get more data. When i save my figure i get every time i receive the message a new identical  file.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-04-19**:
Is the published data actually changing? (rostopic echo -p /yourtopic)...